# Using AIC to compare models with collinear explanatory variables

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, logistic, multicollinearity, aic

I'm using logistic regression to test whether the proportion of seeds to germinate across an elevational gradient is explained by temperature, precipitation, elevation, or other site features that I didn't directly measure. These other features are represented within a categorical variable for site id. My model looks like this:

```
model_1 <- glm(prop_emerged ~ site + temp + precip + elev, family = "binomial", data)
```

Due to an admittedly sub-optimal experimental design, each site has only one value for each temperature and precipitation and each site logically has only a single value for elevation. Due to the lack of site-level variation in these variables, the above model fails due to perfect multicollinearity*. Since the model fails, I can't test if any of the continuous variables explain variation in emergence beyond what's explained by the site id variable.

To get around this, I've considered splitting the model into the following and comparing the AIC/BIC values to see which model is a better predictor of emergence.

```
model_2 <- glm(prop_emerged ~ site, family = "binomial", data)
model_3 <- glm(prop_emerged ~ temp + precip + elev, family = "binomial", data)
```

Since not all of the continuous predictors in model 2 may be important in predicting emergence, I could perform backward selection with AIC to find the optimal model. But as far as I can tell from other online discussions, model selection through AIC is philosophically incompatible with my intended way of assessing the importance of each explanatory variable (likelihood-ratio tests comparing models with and without each variable, comparisons of estimated marginal mean emergence per site and trend-lines of estimated marginal means for continuous variables).

So, my question in general terms is how can I assess the importance of colinear variables in driving a phenomenon? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

- The VIF values for model 1 are ~ 150 but in model_3 (site removed), the VIF values are < 10.

Comment: What are your observational units? Sites? Or something more specific?

Comment: Plots - 25 per site

Comment: Model 3 seems to fail the assumption that your observations are independent - as each of the 25 plots within a site are not independent from each other, and you no longer account for this by including site. How many sites do you have? If you have enough sites maybe you could just pool the plot-level emergence data from each site, and use that as your response, with temp + precip + elev as predictors?

Comment: Hi @rw2 - I have 14 sites but if I pool (i.e. average?) emergence across plots at a site, I'm left with a single estimate per value of elevation, temperature, and precipitation (i.e. 14 rows). Wouldn't I need to have some variation in emergence within each value of temp. precip, and elevation for the model to account for? On the subject of non-independence, I've also considered using site as a random effect for model_3 (but I'm still learning if that's a good idea or not)

Comment: Adding site as a random effect would account for between-site differences and deal with the non-independence, but then you have the same issue - there is no remaining variation in temp. precip. and elev. between plots within a site. For this reason I would calculate the total (or average) proportion emergence at each site, and use that as your response. I'm not sure what else you can do with this experimental design. Other users might have suggestions though...

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thanks a lot for your advice! To circle back to one of the issues I'm facing, do you think it's reasonable to use AIC for variable selection in model_3 and then report p-values for the variables in the optimal (lowest AIC) model?

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me.